# Pine Script : number of bars in a series returned by the security function?

Tags: pine-script

To get the number of bars for the current ticker and timeframe (resolution) you use the built-in `bar_index` (pinescript version 4) or `n` but how do you get the number of bars when using the `security` function to retrieve a series?

Comment: `bar_index` doesn't return the total number of bars in a series. It returns the current bar number. You cannot know the total number of bars on beforehand.

Comment: Well but isn't the last bar index implicitly telling you the total number of bars? The total number of bars is bar_index + 1. My question however is about series returned by calling the strategy function. Any idea or suggestion on that?

Comment: The bar_index remains the same, whether you use security function or not.

Comment: This is not correct as using the `security` function you can specify a timeframe/resolution that's different from the one selected for the currently displayed symbol

Comment: You are correct. The `bar_index` is indeed different on the higher timeframe. I didn't know that. We learn something new everyday :) See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay=true)

bar_index_weekly = security(syminfo.tickerid, "W", bar_index)

plot(bar_index_weekly, "bar_index_weekly")
plot(bar_index, "bar_index_current_timeframe")
```

Comment: Clever suggestion, thank you for sharing :)