# How can I use bar_index to plot the first bar after session starts?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I would like to label every bar starting from number 1 after market opens. So here market opens 9-15 AM IST, and for example selected timeframe is 3 mins. So I would like to label the first bar as 1, then second bar as 2.. so on until the market hour ends which is 3-30 PM IST.

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65870573/pine-script-number-of-bars-in-a-series-returned-by-the-security-function) and [this](https://kodify.net/tradingview/bar-data/bar-number/). But for me I want to restart the bar numbering again from next opening, so it is not helping me. Can anyone offer some ideas how can I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare the session using the `input.session()` + `time()` functions, note that you can also specify a correct timezone using the IANA time zone format.
myCount varialbe will reset at the end of the session, otherwise count every bar in:

```
//@version=5
indicator("session bar counter", overlay = true, max_labels_count = 500)

inputSession = input.session("0915-1530:1234567", "Session") 

inTimeRange = na(time(timeframe.period, inputSession, 'Asia/Calcutta')) == false

myCount = int(na)
myCount := inTimeRange ? nz(myCount[1]) + 1 : 0

if inTimeRange
    label.new(bar_index, high, str.tostring(myCount), color = color(na), textcolor = color.white)
```

[image]

Comment: What is 123456?

Comment: Days of the week included, 1234567 - all week covered.

Comment: ah I see. thanks